# Constructing simple Scala case classes from Strings, strictly without boiler-plate

Tags: scala, constructor, boilerplate, case-class

I seek succinct code to initialize simple Scala case classes from Strings (e.g. a csv line):

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Double)
case class Book(title: String, author: String, year: Int)
case class Country(name: String, population: Int, area: Double)

val amy = Creator.create[Person]("Amy,54.2")
val fred = Creator.create[Person]("Fred,23")
val hamlet = Creator.create[Book]("Hamlet,Shakespeare,1600")
val finland = Creator.create[Country]("Finland,4500000,338424")
```

What's the simplest `Creator` object to do this? I would learn a lot about Scala from seeing a good solution to this.

(Note that companion objects `Person`, `Book` and `Country` should not to be forced to exist. That would be boiler-plate!)

Answer (score 46):

I'm going to give a solution that's about as simple as you can get given some reasonable constraints about type safety (no runtime exceptions, no runtime reflection, etc.), using [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for generic derivation:

```
import scala.util.Try
import shapeless._

trait Creator[A] { def apply(s: String): Option[A] }

object Creator {
  def create[A](s: String)(implicit c: Creator[A]): Option[A] = c(s)

  def instance[A](parse: String => Option[A]): Creator[A] = new Creator[A] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[A] = parse(s)
  }

  implicit val stringCreate: Creator[String] = instance(Some(_))
  implicit val intCreate: Creator[Int] = instance(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
  implicit val doubleCreate: Creator[Double] =
    instance(s => Try(s.toDouble).toOption)

  implicit val hnilCreator: Creator[HNil] =
    instance(s => if (s.isEmpty) Some(HNil) else None)

  private[this] val NextCell = "^([^,]+)(?:,(.+))?$".r

  implicit def hconsCreate[H: Creator, T <: HList: Creator]: Creator[H :: T] =
    instance {
      case NextCell(cell, rest) => for {
        h <- create[H](cell)
        t <- create[T](Option(rest).getOrElse(""))
      } yield h :: t
      case _ => None
    }

  implicit def caseClassCreate[C, R <: HList](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, R],
    rc: Creator[R]
  ): Creator[C] = instance(s => rc(s).map(gen.from))
}
```

This work exactly as specified (although note that the values are wrapped in `Option` to represent the fact that the parsing operation can fail):

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Double)
defined class Person

scala> case class Book(title: String, author: String, year: Int)
defined class Book

scala> case class Country(name: String, population: Int, area: Double)
defined class Country

scala> val amy = Creator.create[Person]("Amy,54.2")
amy: Option[Person] = Some(Person(Amy,54.2))

scala> val fred = Creator.create[Person]("Fred,23")
fred: Option[Person] = Some(Person(Fred,23.0))

scala> val hamlet = Creator.create[Book]("Hamlet,Shakespeare,1600")
hamlet: Option[Book] = Some(Book(Hamlet,Shakespeare,1600))

scala> val finland = Creator.create[Country]("Finland,4500000,338424")
finland: Option[Country] = Some(Country(Finland,4500000,338424.0))
```

`Creator` here is a type class that provides evidence that we can parse a string into a given type. We have to provide explicit instances for basic types like `String`, `Int`, etc., but we can use Shapeless to generically derive instances for case classes (assuming that we have `Creator` instances for all of their member types).

Comment: This is pretty cool Travis! Can you explain this notation a bit `Creator[H :: T]`? How do I read the type here?

Comment: This reads "HList whose head is of type H and whose tail is of type T". T is either another type level cons (H2 ::  T2) or HNil to signify that there are no further values in that list.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. HList is a shapeless construct?

Comment: @marios Yep, it's essentially a tuple with some extra abstractions over arity. I'll add some detail when I'm back at a computer.

Comment: @marios I've just expanded on this answer (probably way too much) in [this blog post](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/).

Comment: That was an amazing read. I strongly recommend anyone puzzled with the details of the solution to read the blog post. Thanks @TravisBrown!

Comment: Thank you, Travis. Your extended blog post was extremely instructive. Very nicely done. I have a question about that: what do the notations `T <: HList: Parser` and `Parser[H :: T]` mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
object Creator {
  def create[T: ClassTag](params: String): T = {
    val ctor = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.getConstructors.head
    val types = ctor.getParameterTypes

    val paramsArray = params.split(",").map(_.trim)

    val paramsWithTypes = paramsArray zip types

    val parameters = paramsWithTypes.map {
      case (param, clas) =>
        clas.getName match {
          case "int" => param.toInt.asInstanceOf[Object] // needed only for AnyVal types
          case "double" => param.toDouble.asInstanceOf[Object] // needed only for AnyVal types
          case _ =>
            val paramConstructor = clas.getConstructor(param.getClass)
            paramConstructor.newInstance(param).asInstanceOf[Object]
        }

    }

    val r = ctor.newInstance(parameters: _*)
    r.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

Comment: I really like the fact that this is simple, with no package dependencies. Of course it will be slow, due to reflection --- but I don't care about that for current purposes. (I'm assuming that the shapeless-based answer does the magic at compile time, without reflection...?!)

Comment: @PerfectTiling The primary problem with this approach is that it's fragile and when it breaks, it breaks at runtime—the performance cost is unlikely to be significant in most cases. And right, there's no runtime reflection in the Shapeless solution (although it does use reflection—see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33580411/334519) for some discussion).