# Create object instance from list of string type arguments

Tags: scala

Given this case class `case class Location(id: BigInt, lat: Double, lng: Double)`

and a list of strings `List("87222", "42.9912987", "-93.9557953")`

I would like to do something like `Location.fromString(listOfString)` in a way `Location` instance is created with string types converted into appropriate types.

Only way I can think of is define `fromString` method in each case class but I'm looking for a more generic solution each class can inherit. For example, I would have `case class Location(...) extends Record`, where `Record` implements `fromString` that does conversion based on argument types defined in `Location` class.

Comment: I just answered a very similar question few days ago, have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585441/constructing-simple-scala-case-classes-from-strings-strictly-without-boiler-pla/33589126#33589126

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally for best performance in such you need to create some macro.

Luckily there is beautiful [shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) with which you could create such generic reader with near-macro performance in no time using [it's generic case class representation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes)

First define typeclass and some instances for reading your fields:

```
trait Read[T] {
  def fromString(s: String): T
}

implicit object readBigInt extends Read[BigInt] {
  def fromString(s: String): BigInt = BigInt(s)
}

implicit object readDouble extends Read[Double] {
  def fromString(s: String): Double = s.toDouble
}
```

Next define your main typeclass:

```
trait ReadSeq[T] {
  def fromStrings(ss: Seq[String]): T
}
```

Now it's shapeless time (thinking about Dalí?) . We create reader for powerful [Heterogenous List](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists), which is almost like `List` but with of statically known length and element types.
It's no harder than to match simple `List`. Just define cases for empty list and cons:

```
import shapeless._

implicit object readHNil extends ReadSeq[HNil] {
  def fromStrings(ss: Seq[String]) = HNil
}

implicit def readHList[X, XS <: HList](implicit head: Read[X], tail: ReadSeq[XS]) =
  new ReadSeq[X :: XS] {
    def fromStrings(ss: Seq[String]) = ss match {
      case s +: rest => (head fromString s) :: (tail fromStrings rest)
    }
  }
```

Now we can use out-of-the-box macro mapping of `HList`s and case classes via `Generic`:

```
implicit def readCase[C, L <: HList](implicit gen: Generic.Aux[C, L], read: ReadSeq[L]) =
  new ReadSeq[C] {
    def fromStrings(ss: Seq[String]) = gen.from(read.fromStrings(ss))
  }
```

Finally we could build our typeclass user:

```
def fromStringSeq[T](ss: Seq[String])(implicit read: ReadSeq[T]) = read.fromStrings(ss)
```

from this point having

```
case class Location(id: BigInt, lat: Double, lng: Double)

val repr = List("87222", "42.9912987", "-93.9557953")
```

you can ensure that

```
fromStringSeq[Location](repr) == Location(BigInt("87222"), 42.9912987, 93.9557953)
```